# Kamcord integration in cocos2d game tutorial

Tags: iphone, ios6, cocos2d-iphone

I have developed a game using cocos2D game engine. Now I want to integrate Kamcord framework in my app to add recording feature. I am not able to find any tutorial on how to integrate Kamcord into the application. Can some one provide me integration code for the tutorial from where to start with?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Humble request - Please atleast give the reason for down voting if you have that power so that I can improve on my mistake.

Comment: i guess the downvote was for asking for a link, which (if one exists) could be found with google and it could at any time disappear from the net. Better to ask for integration steps here. Btw, aren't there any install instructions from the developers?

Comment: see, there you go: https://github.com/kamcord/cocos2d-2.0-kamcord/wiki

Comment: @LearnCocos2D - I am able to find the library but I am not able to find the code tutorial on hoe to implement.. Please can you help me out.

Comment: I posted the link in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an end-to-end Kamcord integration documentation available, but you can find complete working examples at the download page: https://github.com/kamcord/cocos2d-2.0-kamcord/wiki/Download#kamcord-cocos2d-20-examples. If you have any specific questions, please feel free to email hello@kamcord.com